# 0 Weight Vertices still affecting deforming bones

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have an issue with Automatic Weights with my human character, it fails. So I'm trying to weight paint manually, however strange things happen:

[image]

There's no weight painted under the neck. You don't have to care about other vertex groups, I already checked many times, there's no weight under the neck.

However when I rotate the neck bone, vertices at the end of the mesh still affecting on neck/head bones even it is 0 weighted:

[image]
[image]

I don't know why this happens, those vertices doesn't have any vertex group, all 0 weight painted.

What should I check to fix this issue? Any advice will very appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a very small amount of weight was assigned to those vertices. The value was too small so in weight paint mode I couldn't see that properly because it was just totally blue.

So I remove the each vertex group one by one, and find the bone that making this issue and repaint to 0 weight under the neck, and now it works.